# Everytime on browser refresh page redirects to index page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to React. My react app is running well but have a small problem. Whenever I navigate to some other pages and refresh the page there, then its coming back to home page.

**App**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const loggedin = useSelector((state) => state.LoginSlice.loggedin);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(check_login_status());
}, [dispatch]);

return (
  <>
    <Router>
      {loggedin ? (
        <div>
          <LayoutAuth />
          <br />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>{/* <LayoutNoauth /> */}</div>
      )}
      <div className="page_container">
        <AppRoute loggedin={loggedin} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </>
);
```

**AppRoute**

```
function AppRoute({ loggedin }) {
  return (
    <Routes>
      {!loggedin && (
        <>
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        </>
      )}
      {loggedin && (
        <>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/versions" element={<VersionPage />} />
          <Route path="/pgeactivity" element={<PgeActivityPage />} />
        </>
      )}
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={loggedin ? "/home" : "/login"} />} />  //<-- this may be the problem
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Note if I comment out the marked line in AppRoute, it is working but another problem arise that after log-in when I navigate to home page, on browser back button click it is navigating to log-in page again. Same thing happens on log-out.

I have attached a image please check it for clarification.
[image]

Anyone kindly suggest me what to do.
Thank you.

Comment: In the App file instead of `Router` use `BrowserRouter`. Also, check when you navigate does it change URL? also url matches your define route? If its not match then it will go to last line with * and navigate to home page.

Comment: @Dhaval, thanks for replying. I'm using BrowserRouter like this: 
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
Also i checked, url is being changing like this:
https://domain/home
https://domain/versions
etc
and the url is matching the route

Comment: Using the `useLocation` hook. Print your location in the console and check. Also, giving a sample code to reproduce the issue at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) will be good.

Comment: The animated image hides one of the most important details of the issue, what the URL path is as you are doing this. Can you [edit] to include all the relevant code you are working with as part of a complete [mcve]? What is the `check_login_status` action doing? What are the redux code for the `loggedin` state?

Comment: I am sorry Drew, due to privacy issue, I had to hide that url. But as you asked url is changing or not, the answer is yes. The url is having the navigation path. I am sharing the sample snippet for you and @Dhaval. Please check. https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-demo-m75e30?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with how you initialize `loggedin` state in redux. When you initialize it will initialize with false and it requires a localStoreage change event or manually firing the event to call that `useSelector` to update the value. But when you refresh it will take the default value as false and never to do changes until you do login/logout again.

To fix the issue you have to initialize `loggedin` state in redux with the `localStorage` state. Do change in `Login.Slice.js` file.

```
const initialState = {
  loggedin: localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "yes"
};
```

You can have a working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-demo-forked-f58q8p.

You can get details about localStorage. Its storage store data as key/value pair. `localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "yes"` will check does your localStorage with key `loggedin` have value `yes`. If yes then return true else false.

Also, `localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "yes"` is same as `localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "yes" ? true : false`. The first expression return true/false based on that you are doing condition. So if value is true then expression will be `true ? true : false` which not make much sense.

Comment: wow. that's working. @Dhaval if you mind, can you tell what does  `localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "yes"` mean and how it is different from `localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "yes" ? true : false`

Comment: Updated answer with details please check.